# Data exposure for HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

A question has arisen at our company regarding data security.  In our environment, we are using HighCharts to publish graphs internally on our intranet.  The javascript code, HTML code and the data reside on our internal servers, behind our firewall.  However, as currently implemented, we are referencing the HighCharts javascript libraries externally (eg, at http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js).

In this setting, do the charted data points get sent through the internet?  Ie are we exposing our data outside of our intranet if we call the javascript library above?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use the default exporting library in highcharts, then yes - that sends the chart information to an external server (but you can set up your own very easily: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server ).  If you are not using the export server, there is no communication back to the Highcharts source.  OTOH, if you are running it on your intranet, I cannot see a reason to not host it locally as well...

Comment: You can download highcharts.js and upload to your own local webserver. Then load from that location instead of communication with our CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. That file will be downloaded to the browser and all the calculations will be done locally.